# Best approach to having multiple DatagramChannels working on one port

Tags: java, udp

Lately I've been messing around a lot with DatagramChannels, and have made a pretty complicated and well functioning system, to work with them on two sides of the connection.
However, i've run into a problem. While sanity-checking my connection protocol, i realised that i have a pretty big problem with running multiple channels on one port. it seems that unlike java's TCP sockets, java's udp sockets do not properly route the packets as they arrive to the appropriate channel.
more specifically, it appears that if i have two channels, on two threads, waiting for a packet, both on the same port, but connected to different outputs, the first one that was bound will be the one to get the packet, even if it arrives from the other channel's connection. the problem is that it filters it out automatically (as it should), and as a result, that packet is fully lost forever, and the second channel will just keep on waiting.
because of technical limitations, i need the server's side to run on exactly one port, which leaves me baffled as to what should i do.
am i doing something wrong? also, is this something that is fixed by using a selector? i'm a bit new to DatagramSockets and channels, as i've mostly used the tcp ones in java up until now.

i've also got some of the sanity check's test code here to verify it, it's a bit messy, but there are two timers constantly trying to receive packets from the same connection, and only one of them is receiving.
by changing which timer task runs first, i'm able to change which one gets the packets. what baffles me even more though is the fact that the first timer task is able to work with each now socket, while still not letting the "outsider channel" receive even a single packet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    runServer();
    runClient();
}

public static void runClient() {
    DatagramChannel channel;
    try {
        channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        channel.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8000));
        channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8001));
        while(true) {
        channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("let's see who wins".getBytes()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class Channel{

    DatagramChannel channel;
    int number;
    public Channel(int number) {
        try {
            channel = DatagramChannel.open();
            this.number = number;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static boolean outsiderLost = false;

// client on port 8000
// server on port 8001
public static void runServer() {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[300]);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean firstTime = true;
                int i = 0;
                Channel channel = new Channel(i);
                DatagramChannel channel1 = channel.channel;
                while(true) {
                try {
                    if(firstTime) {
                        channel1.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
                        channel1.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8001));
                        channel1.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8000));
                        channel1.configureBlocking(true);
                        firstTime = false;
                    } else {
                    SocketAddress add = channel1.receive(buf);
                    i++;
                    channel = new Channel(i);
                    channel1 = channel.channel;
                    channel1.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
                    channel1.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8001));
                    channel1.connect(add);
                    buf.clear();
                    System.out.println("channel " + channel.number + " wins");
                    outsiderLost = true;
                }} catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }

        }, 500);
        Timer timer2 = new Timer();
        timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DatagramChannel channel1 = null;
                try {
                    channel1 = DatagramChannel.open();
                    channel1.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
                    channel1.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8001));
                    channel1.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8000));
                    channel1.configureBlocking(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while(!outsiderLost) {
                    try {
                        channel1.read(buf);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    buf.clear();
                    System.out.println("outsider wins");
                    outsiderLost = true;
                }
            }

        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think an [mcve] is in order.

Comment: added the code i used to diagnose exactly where the packets were lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up creating one reader channel that actually reads on the server, and then reroutes the packets to the different sender channels to be processed and then send a response.